# How to see what command is executed by Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line, intellij-15

Is there any way of seeing what commands is Intellij executing to run tests? There is nothing like that in the Run or Debug views.

Basically I want the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518692/is-there-a-way-to-see-what-commands-are-executed-by-eclipse), but for Intellij (15).

Comment: Which tests? When I run cucumber or karma tests, it shows me the command line it used in the output panel

Comment: @JuanMendes: Unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Test Runner Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/test-runner-tab.html?origin=old_help) has an output pane (see the pane labelled "4" in from the link). The first line of this is usually the command used to start the tests.

Comment: Sí señora. A 20k character line is not what I was expecting, but sure looks like the answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit longer than one would expect! But it's possible to find the info you need in there, usually by taking out some of the IntelliJ specific stuff.